# count number of n grams in text

Tags: python

```
import re
N = 2
list = []
counts = dict()
ngarms = []
with open('man.txt','r',encoding='cp1251') as f:
        for sent in f:
            sent = sent.lower()
            sent = re.sub('[0-9A-z\'\"`\|\/\+\#\,\)\(\?\!\B\-\:\=\;\.\«\»\-\—]', '', sent)
            sent = sent.split()
            for word in sent:
                word = word.lower()
                list.append(word)


grams = [list[i:i+N] for i in range(len(list)-N)]
    for gram in grams:
        if gram not in counts:
           counts[word] = 1
        else:
           counts[word] += 1
```

I try to count nubber of each Ngram in the text, but when do it using method with dictionary I get error:
 if gram not in counts:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

man.txt looks like this:

> Ми набрали стільки різної музики, що слухати її вже ніхто не хотів. Якісь 
>      — Сільві, це зміна тиску, — кажу я їй
>      — Двірники тут не допоможуть. Джаз, до речі, теж.
>      Так уже складається, що я маю пити сам. Між Сільві й Ґашпером існує джентльменська угода, що десь там після умовного перетину австрійсько-німецького кордону він її підмінить за кермом, а на автобані пити він все ж таки не наважується, тож я собі відкриваю чергову банку, зідравши з неї чеку, й намагаюсь підтримувати розмову. Загалом, перша сотня кілометрів мені знайома, торік я їздив тут автостопом, мене тоді підібрав якийсь божевільний панк, який весь час нервово пив спрайт, його сушило, схоже він був з обкурки, але гнав таки на Захід, бо мусив, уже не знаю, що там у нього було, може, мама чекала, однак вигляд у нього був нещасний. Коли я дістав з наплічника пляшку води, він спитався, чи це не водка бува, у вас же там, в Росії, всі п’ють водку, ні, не водка, кажу, і він весело розсміявся. Тупий якийсь панк трапився. Зараз я намагаюсь переповісти все це Сільві, виловлюючи її увагу з атональних джазових ям і порожнин, Сільві погоджується — так, справді тупий панк, що тут скажеш, розмова не в’яжеться, і я відкриваю наступну банку, все одно поки що нічого цікавого — голі пасовища, безлисті лісосмуги, печальна березнева Австро-Угорщина, мабуть, саме такою її і запам’ятали російські піхотинці навесні 45-го, депресивний доволі ландшафт, ось вони і хуячили наліво і направо елітні дивізії нещасних націонал-соціалістів. У цей час касета добігає кінця і тут таки починає розкручуватись у зворотньому напрямку, новий джаз знову бере за горло, і я заходжуся шукати під кріслами забутого і присипаного фісташками старого-доброго Лу Ріда. «Джаз — музика для товстих», — кажу я Сільві й міняю касети. Десь уже на німецькій території нам трапилася військова колона, що розтяглась на добрих два десятки кілометрів.

It is a book

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please let us know how ``man.txt`` looks like and elaborate more on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know how to get ngarms but I can not count number of each ngarm in this text

Comment: So you have a list named ``list``, that contains all words from the file as an individual element. And you are trying to count the number of occurrences of the word *ngarm*, right?

Comment: Not word ngram but n-gram is a contiguous sequence of n items from a given sequence of text or speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the indentation mistakes in your code are actually only copy/paste mistakes, the issue is that `grams` is a list of list, which contains 2 elements each in the inner list.

When you do - `for gram in grams:` , you are getting the inner list in `gram` variable which is a list, then you are trying to check whether the `gram` variable is a `key` in the `counts` dictionary.

This leads to error, because we cannot use `list` as keys for dictionary , since they are not hashable.

I am not clearly sure what the complete ask is, but an example of how to fix the issue would be to iterate through each `gram` again and check if the elements inside the inner list are present in the `counts` dictionary.

Example -

```
for gram in grams:
    for g in gram:
        if g not in counts:
            counts[word] = 1
        else:
            counts[word] += 1
```

But I don't think using `word` over there is correct, since it would most probably use the last value that of `word` from within the `with` block. Maybe you need to use `g` variable instead as I used above???

Also, its advised that you do not use `list` as the name of a variable since it overwrites the built-in `list()` function.

---

Since the ask is that the OP wants to count the number of times each sequence of words come in the text. You can do it by creating `grams` list as a list of all sequences by using `join` , for example and then using his own example -

grams = [' '.join(list[i:i+N]) for i in range(len(list)-N)]
for gram in grams:
    if gram not in counts:
        counts[word] = 1
    else:
        counts[word] += 1

Comment: maybe my ask was not very exact, I need to count have many time each sequence of words for example "I am" appears in the text

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution for your case

Comment: resolution was so easy, very grateful!

Comment: and in general I want to aply Bayes' theorem to text to count probabilities for each n-grams in the text.

Comment: You are welcome, for the bayes theoron , I am not sure about that

Comment: so first you need to count number of each n-gram and then divide it to number of appearance of the first element of that n-gram

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `list` contains each word of the file as a list element and you are looking for the word *ngram*, just test each list element for equality:

```
ngrams = [word for word in list if word == "ngram"]
print len(ngrams)
```

Comment: Not word ngram but n-gram is a contiguous sequence of n items from a given sequence of text or speech